# Processing numbers from a string and adding to find average score

Tags: java, file-io

Here's my current [code](http://pastebin.com/JQQA5FHt), and here's my current output:

```
This program will calculate an overall score for a diver, based on individual dives.
The diver's score for dive 1 is 79.80. 
The diver's score for dive 2 is 49.80. 

The average score for these dives is 64.80.
```

Here's the page with the [specifications](http://cs.millersville.edu/~zoppetti/161/Lab9.html).

Bascically this program takes a string from a file that looks like:

```
1 2.5 8.5 8.0 8.5 9.5 9.0 7.5 6.5
```

where the `1` is the dive number, the `2.5` is the difficulty, and the rest are the scores. I add up all of the scores except for the highest and lowest, multiply by the difficulty, and multiply by 0.6 to get my score for the dive.

What I'm having problems with is this: My dive 2 score is correct but my dive 1 score is incorrect. I'm really not quite sure why.

I'd really appreciate help; I've racked my brain to find out why it is this way but I can't seem to figure it out. Thank you for looking, I appreciate it.

Edit: Here's the code for you guys:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Dive {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        printIntro();

        Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("DiveData.txt"));

        processDives(fileScanner);
    }

    public static void printIntro() {
        System.out
                .println("Welcome to the Diver Scoring program."
                        + "\nThis program will calculate an overall score for a diver, based on individual dives.");
    }

    public static void processDives(Scanner fileScanner) {
        double avg = 0;
        int count = 0;

        while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
            int diveNumber = fileScanner.nextInt();
            String diveLine = fileScanner.nextLine();
            double score = calculateDiveScore(diveLine);
            avg += score;

            System.out.printf("The diver's score for dive " + diveNumber
                    + " is " + "%.2f. \n", score);

            count++;
            diveNumber = 0;
        }
        System.out.printf("\nThe average score for these dives is "
                + "%.2f. \n", avg / (double) count);
    }

    public static double calculateDiveScore(String diveLine) {
        double score = 0.0;
        String subNumbers = "";
        double difficulty = Double.parseDouble(diveLine.substring(1, 4));
        diveLine = diveLine.substring(5);
        double max = -500, min = 500;

        for (int i = 0; i < diveLine.length(); i++) {

            // if we're getting something other than a space, add it to the
            // string. We'll do the calculations while we have spaces.
            if (diveLine.charAt(i) != ' ') {
                subNumbers += diveLine.charAt(i);
            } else {
                double val = Double.parseDouble(subNumbers);
                // if the score is neither largest nor smallest, add it to total
                // score.
                if (Math.max(val, max) == max && Math.min(val, min) == min) {
                    score += val;
                }

                // if it is either largest or smallest, add previous largest or
                // smallest and set current to largest or smallest.
                if (Math.max(val, max) == val) {
                    if (max != -500)
                        score += max;
                    max = val;
                } else if (Math.min(val, min) == val) {
                    if (min != 500)
                        score += min;
                    min = val;
                }
                subNumbers = "";
            }
        }

        //check the last number to see if it's a max or a min
        if (Math.max(Double.parseDouble(subNumbers), max) == Double
                .parseDouble(subNumbers)) {
            score += max;
        } else if (Math.min(Double.parseDouble(subNumbers), min) == Double
                .parseDouble(subNumbers)) {
            score += min;
        }

        return score * difficulty * 0.6;
    }
}
```

And the answer can be found here:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Dive {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        printIntro();

        Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("DiveData.txt"));

        processDives(fileScanner);
    }

    public static void printIntro() {
        System.out
                .println("Welcome to the Diver Scoring program."
                        + "\nThis program will calculate an overall score for a diver, based on individual dives.");
    }

    public static void processDives(Scanner fileScanner) {
        double avg = 0;
        int count = 0;

        while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
            int diveNumber = fileScanner.nextInt();
            String diveLine = fileScanner.nextLine();
            double score = calculateDiveScore(diveLine);
            avg += score;

            System.out.printf("The diver's score for dive " + diveNumber
                    + " is " + "%.2f. \n", score);

            count++;
            diveNumber = 0;
        }
        System.out.printf("\nThe average score for these dives is " + "%.2f.",
                avg / (double) count);
    }

    public static double calculateDiveScore(String diveLine) {

        diveLine = diveLine.substring(1);
        String[] fields = diveLine.split(" ");
        double difficulty = Double.parseDouble(fields[0]);
        double[] scores = new double[fields.length - 1];
        double max = -500.0, min = 500.0, score = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < fields.length - 1; i++) {
            scores[i] = Double.parseDouble(fields[i + 1]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
            if (Math.max(scores[i], max) == scores[i])
                max = scores[i];
            if (Math.min(scores[i], min) == scores[i])
                min = scores[i];
            score += scores[i];
        }

        score -= max;
        score -= min;

        return score * difficulty * 0.6;
    }
}
```

([Also found here on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/evai8sdB))

Comment: Much confusion was caused in this question because you only linked to your code. SO-ers are used to seeing code inline. I see that in the meantime you've found the answer yourself, but there's another problem because that fact is not very visible. Could you post your own answer and accept it so it will be clear to future vistors?

Comment: Hopefully that looks better, Marko. Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is homework, the best way for you to learn would probably to read the entire string in, then create a scanner over the String, then iterate over it with getDouble().

So:

```
for(iterate over number of lines) {

    String yourString = "blah";

    ... create Scanner pointing to yourString...

    while(scanner has a double) {

        double nextNum = get next double from scanner;
        ... Do something with that double...
    }
}
```

If you need any help on the specifics, feel free to ask.

Edit: woops, missed that link to your code. Ignore the 'post your code' bit.

Comment: I think I do a fine job of reading it and that's not where the problem lies. There's a pretty large constraint on how I'm supposed to do stuff due to the class being a comp sci 100 level course. I appreciate the tip though for future reference

Comment: Well you're already using a Scanner earlier, so I don't see any reason you can't use it later.

Edit: And the reason you're having issues is the way you're checking and storing your max and min. Run your program and see what happens if the numbers constantly increase: i.e. 1.0 2.0 3.0

Comment: You're right, but it actually only works if they consistently decrease

Comment: It has issues either way. 1.0 2.0 3.0  with a difficult of 2 should return 2.4, but your code returns 3.6

Comment: what I meant is I get the correct answer if the dive scores always decrease

Comment: In case anyone finds this thread and wants the answer, here's my final (working) code: http://pastebin.com/evai8sdB

Answer (score 1):

Use [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) for this. The way you are *parsing* the line of scores is extremely overly complicated and error prone.

Here is a ***hint*** given the line: ***this is just pseudo-code, to show the approach***

```
final String s = "1 2.5 8.5 8.0 8.5 9.5 9.0 7.5 6.5";
final String[] fields = s.split(" ");
// get the metadata
final int diveNumber = Integer.parseInt(fields[0]);
final double difficulty = Double.parseDouble(fields[1]);
// convert the scores 
final double[] scores = new double[fields.length - 2];
for (int i = 2; i < fields.length; i++ )
{
   scores[i] = Double.parseDouble(fields[i]);  
}

// the rest is left as an exercise to the reader
```

Personally I would convert all the raw arrays to `List` instances just to make working with them easier, but that is another lesson.

Comment: my example was not meant to be copy and paste, this is homework, it was meant to be a **hint** in the right direction towards the most idiomatic way to do this in Java.

Comment: `fields[0]` is a empty string `""` for some reason, use some debugging techniques to figure it out. There is probably some stray characters or something on that line.

Comment: The way java handles .split() that should work to at least split up my string into the fields array, which means fields[0] *should* be the int correlating to the dive number - instead it's just an empty field?

Comment: In case anyone finds this thread and wants the answer, here's my final (working) code: http://pastebin.com/evai8sdB